# How to align a picture inside a <div>, so as to have the same width?

Tags: css, html, alignment

**How** can I align a picture inside a `div` container so it fits with the width?

This is how far I got

```html
<head>

<style>
#left {
 background-color:#81CFE0;
 height:100%;
 width:25%;
 float:left;
}

#img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
</style>

<meta charset="utf-8">

</head>

<body>

<div id="left">
<img src="/img/001.jpg">
This is a Picture of something representing something

</body>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of mistakes in your code but this should work:

```css
#left {
  background-color:#81CFE0;
  height:100%;
  width:25%;
  float:left;
}

img {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
  <img src="/img/001.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: So this would make every picture used align to the width. What can I do to only have it align when it's needed?